# Cast fails from ICollection<TestCastChild> to ICollection<ICastBase>

Tags: c#

I'm using reflection to get a property that is a `ICollection<TestCastChild>` and cast it as a `ICollection<ICastBase>`.  TestCastChild implement's ICastBase.  When I try to cast the collection, the cast fails.  I'm sure that I'm missing something simple.  I can't see why this fails.

```
public interface ICastBase
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface ICastChild : ICastBase
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TestCastBase : ICastBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestCastChild : TestCastBase, ICastChild
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestCastParent : TestCastBase
{
    public virtual ICollection<TestCastChild> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then to test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCast()
{
    var parent = new TestCastParent();
    parent.Children = parent.Children ?? new List<TestCastChild>();
    parent.Children.Add(new TestCastChild{Name = "a"});
    parent.Children.Add(new TestCastChild { Name = "b"});
    parent.Children.Add(new TestCastChild { Name = "c"});

    var propInfos = parent.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propInfos)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add") != null)
        {
            var tmpVal = propertyInfo.GetValue(parent);
            //This evaluates to null
            var cast1 = tmpVal as ICollection<ICastBase>; 
            //This evaluates to null
            var cast2 = tmpVal as ICollection<ICastChild>;
            //This evaluates to the expected value
            var cast3 = tmpVal as ICollection<TestCastChild>;
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate.  After seeing the answer here, I was able to search on 'covariant' and find other answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **cannot** cast from `ICollection<Derived>` to `ICollection<Base>`, as `ICollection<T>` is not *covariant*.

If it were possible, you could cast an `ICollection<Dog>` to `ICollection<Mammal>` and then add a `Cat` to the collection, as it's a `Mammal` too.

What you *can* do, is cast from `IReadOnlyCollection<Derived>` to `IReadOnlyCollection<Base>` as `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>` is *covariant*. If your concrete collection type implements `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>` (and `List<T>` does) it will work just fine, but you'll only get a read only interface to the underlying collection. This way, type safety is still preserved.

Note that you can also use `IReadOnlyList<out T>`, which inherits from `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>` and it adds an indexer.